# Disable python logger output

Tags: python, windows, logging

I have python script for **Python 2.7.10** that looks like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.info("Hello, world!");
```

Is it possible to somehow run this script **from Powershell** on **Windows** machine so it produces no output? I've tried redirecting output to file

```
C:\Python2.7\python.exe C:\Users\User\script.py > output.txt
```

But it didn't help and script writes `Hello, world!` string to console.

Comment: Did you try it `logger.propagate = False`? Or `2> nul` only for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect all output to null:

```
command > nul 2>&1
```

or

`2> nul`

to kill stderr

Finally to outputfile:

```
command > a.txt 2>&1
```

In powershell:

```
2>&1>$null
2>&1 | out-null
```

From:

https://serverfault.com/questions/132963/windows-redirect-stdout-and-stderror-to-nothing

Comment: Thank you very much, Destrif!